# How to merge two columns into a single column?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to get a single column out of two.
I have a expression "l_entity_key~r_entity_key" and for the LHS and RHS fields i have l_entity_key,r_entity_key columns in "rule" table respectively.

My actual requirement is to find all the values for given entity_key or l_entity_key,r_entity_key where l_entity_key=10 or r_entity_key=10.
e.g

```
10~11
10~13
6~10
4~10
```

The value 10 can be present on either side in the expression,what i want are the values `11,13,6,4`.

The basic sql query that i have tried to achieve above result is:

```
SELECT L_ENTITY_KEY, R_ENTITY_KEY FROM RULE 
WHERE L_TYPE = 'Role' 
AND R_TYPE='Role' 
AND L_ENTITY_KEY = 10
OR R_ENTITY_KEY = 10;
```

Current Output:

```
L_ENTITY_KEY    R_ENTITY_KEY
------------    ------------
          9              10
         10              11
          4              10
          6              10
```

Expected Output:

```
ENTITY_KEY
----------
        9
       11
        4
        6
```

I tried enhancing the basic query,tried merging the two columns into one to at least get close to the desired outcome,tried self join,right outer join and other ways but i am not getting the expected output.Not sharing the other queries to avoid confusion as they were not near to desired output.

How i can do this?

Answer (score 1):

This will union the two results:

```
SELECT L_ENTITY_KEY as ENTITY_KEY FROM RULE 
WHERE L_TYPE = 'Role' 
AND R_TYPE='Role' 
AND R_ENTITY_KEY = 10
  UNION
SELECT R_ENTITY_KEY FROM RULE 
WHERE L_TYPE = 'Role' 
AND R_TYPE='Role' 
AND L_ENTITY_KEY = 10;
```

You need to use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` if you want to keep duplicates (i.e. two rows of `4` for rows `4~10` and `10~4`).

Comment: Thanks @Jiri,your solutions helps

Answer (score 1):

Use a `case` expression to the return the associated value. Something like:

```
SELECT case when L_ENTITY_KEY = 10 then R_ENTITY_KEY else L_ENTITY_KEY end
FROM RULE 
WHERE (L_TYPE = 'Role' AND L_ENTITY_KEY = 10)
   OR (R_TYPE = 'Role' AND R_ENTITY_KEY = 10)
```

Comment: Thanks @jarlh,i haven't used case anytime,learned a new thing,even this is working for me.If comparing Union ,case ,which one is better performance wise?

Comment: The union quwery will read the table twice, and make effort eliminating duplicates. I.e. case solution will be faster.